# How do i turn an string into variables and still get a good output

Tags: php, output, echo

How do i turn an string  into variables and still get a good output.

```
$text = "showandreturn";

$disp = str_split($text, 2); 

$firstnum = 3;

for($b = 0; $b<$firstnum; $b++){

    $a = "$disp[$b]"; #showan

}

$b = "ENDED";

for($b = $firstnum; $b<sizeof($disp); $b++){

    $c = "$disp[$b]"; #dreturn

    echo = "$a$b$c";
}
```

my current output with this code is . `andranetanurann` ..
And I want  beter result like `showanENDEDdreturn`

Thanks for your time and understanding..

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are overwriting your variables every time it loops so only the result of the last loop is stored in the variable.

This code should return the required output.

```
$text = "showandreturn";
$disp = str_split($text, 2);
$num = 3;
$a = '';
$c = '';
for($b = 0; $b<$num; $b++){
    $a .= $disp[$b];
}
$b = "ENDED";
for($bn = $num; $bn<sizeof($disp); $bn++){
    $c .= $disp[$bn];
}
echo $a.$b.$c;
```

Comment: That a great knowledge for me today but how do i add a comm to each output result from  `showanENDEDdreturn`  to like  `sh,ow,an,ENDED,dreturn`  thanks for your returns

Comment: Change line 7 to `$a .= $disp[$b] . ',';` and line 9 to `$b = "ENDED,";`. Please read this for clearification: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put ENDED in the middle of the string?
In that case have a look at this:

```
$text = "showandreturn";
$b = "ENDED";

$len = strlen($text); // lenght of string
// Output half string + $b + rest of string
Echo substr($text, 0, floor($len/2)) . $b . substr($text, floor($len/2));
```

https://3v4l.org/Ea6tn

Answer (score -1):

**Alternative 1**

What you need is [variables variable](http://php.net/en/language.variables.variable)

```
$foo = 'bar';
$foo = 'magic';

echo $foo; //Outputs magic
```

**Alternative 2:**

you can check [http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php](http://parse_str)

```
parse_str($"My Value=Something");
echo $My_Value; // Something
```

**Alternative 3:**

```
echo eval('return $'. $string . ';');
```

Comment: Why the downvote? OP asks "How do I turn an string into variables?" and this is how you can do it in PHP.

Comment: I still get unknow output with your alternative 1 example can you give me coding example of your alternative 2 or 3 ?